# Selenium web driver not loading auto suggestion

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

When loading this website through selenium webdriver (chrome windows), the search bar will now show auto suggestion. 
https://www.avnet.com/wps/portal/us

This behavior can be reproduced in a selenium session, even with manual clicking and as long as in a normal chrome session, the auto suggestion show up no problem.

Screenshot selenium chrome
[image]

Screenshot regular chrome
[image]

Is this a problem with the website or the rendering of selenium webdriver caused this?
I always thought the webdriver is suppose to be the same rendering as regular chrome?

I am trying to web crawl the auto complete but it is not even showing up in the HTML files.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
executable_path=r'C:\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.avnet.com/wps/portal/us')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am getting the below error:-
disconnected: unable to connect to renderer

Check the same URL in selenium control browser doing F12 and you can see there are some 403 errors. It seems like some authentication issue or some required value not passed properly.Though, I am not a developer and trying to point the difference which may help.

[image]